# Can I Force CKEditor To Make The First Line An H1?

Tags: ckeditor

Can I force CKEditor to always make the first line H1 by default?  Then, after hitting enter, I want everything else to be "normal" by default.

The reason is essentially to seamlessly generate a title without requiring a separate title field.

[image: CKEditor Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

No, it's (probably) impossible. Mostly because you'd need to hack selection, block all the commands except H1 format and so on. You'd spend a lot of time but the result would be hacky and unstable, totally not worth your effort. Simply, this is not what CKEditor has been made for.

The fastest way to do this is to implement a separate field in the form (`<input>`) or, if you want to have a rich editing features (like links or colors in `<h1>`), create an [inline editor instance](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/inline.html) out of `<h1>` like

```
<h1 contenteditable="true" id="title">Title</h1>

CKEDITOR.inline( 'title', { ...config } );
```

and collect the value using `CKEDITOR.instances.title.getData()`. There's a [`editor#change`](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/saveajax.html) event, that might be helpful if you decide to synchronise your inline editor with a hidden field in a form.